# Protractor cant see the file just downloaded

Tags: protractor

```
//gives count of downloads in download folder.

    this.getCountOfDownloads = function (fileName,elementToClick) {

        //provides a way to look for filenames matching a certain pattern (in the worst case, you can wait for the *.* - basically, any file to appear)
        var glob = require("glob");
        var filesArray = glob.sync("./src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads/"+"*.xlsx");

        console.log("sizee",filesArray.length);

        browser.driver.wait(function () {
            elementToClick.click();//to download

            if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0) {
                // this check is necessary because `glob.sync` can return
                // an empty list, which will be considered as a valid output
                // making the wait to end.

                return filesArray;
            }
        }, 4444).then(function (filesArray) {
            console.log("sizee",filesArray[0]);



            // now we have the filename and can do whatever we want
        });
        browser.sleep(5555); console.log("sizee",filesArray.length);
    };
```

`elemtclick` downloads file.

I can see in `intelj` when  i click sync button

at first it is empty. Then i run this and it shows size as 0 at both console output. Then in next run, it becomes 1 because the file downloaded before.

`filesarray> 0` is not becoming true.

I put `browsersleep` after `elementclick` but still doesnot wait for file or does not sync with it.

What i want to do is

- I get the counts of downloading before the operation
- I get the counts affer downloaded
- I expect count = currentcount-1

but it cant see file :(,
i thinkk i have to refresh session but maybe there is a nother way

Comment: I think you are running into an asynchronous issues.  console.log() does not wait for browser.sleep.  It happens instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into an asynchronous issues. console.log() does not wait for browser.sleep. It happens instantly.
I think you would need to call glob.sync again, but I don't know that code.

```
//gives count of downloads in download folder.

this.getCountOfDownloads = function (fileName,elementToClick) {

  //provides a way to look for filenames matching a certain pattern (in the worst case, you can wait for the *.* - basically, any file to appear)
  var glob = require("glob");
  var filesArray = glob.sync("./src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads/"+"*.xlsx");

  console.log("sizee",filesArray.length);

  browser.driver.wait(function () {
    elementToClick.click();//to download
    browser.sleep(5555);
    filesArray = glob.sync("./src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads/"+"*.xlsx");
    console.log("sizee",filesArray.length);

    if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0) {
      // this check is necessary because `glob.sync` can return
      // an empty list, which will be considered as a valid output
      // making the wait to end.

      return filesArray.length;
    }
  }, 4444).then(function (filesArray) {
    console.log("sizee",filesArray[0]);
    // now we have the filename and can do whatever we want
  });
};
```